# JPA javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

While execute the below query,

```
SELECT
    systimestamp + interval '-150' minute 
FROM
    DUAL

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery);
List<Object> = query.getResultList();
```

I got the below exeption,

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101
```

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

I need more details to answer your question, but if I'm thinking the same you need, you should add this:

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
```

into your application-context.xml file, according to your database, this example is for Oracle using a ojdbc.jar.

Your Exception is because hibernate doesn't know how to get communicated with your database.

Hope it helps to you.